# DataTable Select & DataView Sort

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

Quick Question.
When I use a DataTable.Select("..") without a Sort condition after using a DataView to Sort the DataTable, should the records be returned in Sorted order ?
Using this method I find that in some cases the records aren't being returned in the correct order, it's hit and miss as well - sometimes they are sometimes they aren't. 
If I specify a sort condition to the Select then it all works fine, but the performance implications are drastic for large DataTables.

I've tried using the DataView RowFilter to reduce the hitset but every time I change the RowFilter the performance goes south

```
MyDtable.Load(MyReader);  // its am Oracle DataReader
MyView = new DataView(MYDtable);
MyView.Sort = "CODE, TABLE DESC";

DataRow[] MyRecs = MyDtable.Select("TABLE > 'FREDDO' AND CODE > '661991'");
```

The number of records returned is always correct, it's just the order that may vary (sometimes)

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

John,

Applying a sort order to a DataView does not change the underlying DataTable it represents.  So your code snippet using both DataView properties and DataTable.Select() method will not work as you intended.

When sorting and filtering, you must choose which method is best for presenting and maintaining the data.  Here are sorting and filtering usages examples for both DataTable and DataView.

**Using DataTable**

Syntax:

```
public System.Data.DataRow[] Select (string filterExpression, string sort);
```

Example:

```
DataRow[] MyRecs = MyDTable.Select("TABLE > 'FREDDO' AND CODE > '661991'", "CODE, TABLE DESC");

foreach (DataRow rec in MyRecs)
{   . . . .   }
```

Reference: [DataTable.Select() Method Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_)

**Using DataView**

Example:

```
DataView MyView = new DataView(MyDTable);
MyView.Sort = "CODE, TABLE DESC";
MyView.RowFilter = "TABLE > 'FREDDO' AND CODE > '661991'";
```

Reference: [DataView.RowFilter Property Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8)

*Note the link takes you to Microsoft’s RowFilter property reference page, the included example shows usage information for both RowFilter and Sort properties.*

Or

Syntax:

```
 public DataView (System.Data.DataTable table, string RowFilter, string Sort,
     System.Data.DataViewRowState RowState);
```

Example:

```
DataView MyView = new DataView(
    MyDTable,
    "TABLE > 'FREDDO' AND CODE > '661991'",
    "CODE, TABLE DESC",
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

foreach (  DataRowView rec in MyView )
{   . . . .   }
```

Reference: [DataView Class Constructor Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataView__ctor_System_Data_DataTable_System_String_System_String_System_Data_DataViewRowState_)

Both methods will return the data filtered and sorted correctly.  The difference is in how the data is being returned.  You must choose the method whose return object best suit your needs.